# Django ON UPDATE setting for Foreign Keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

Why does Django not have an ON UPDATE setting for foreign keys?  The ForeignKey model only has on_delete.

Comment: Do you mean the ForeignKey model only has `on_delete`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why is the same reason why any feature is lacking in any product — no one has implemented it yet.

I would guess that `on_update` is less commonly needed than `on_delete`, because of the popularity of using auto-increment id's as primary keys, which most often have no need to be updated. So the feature of `on_update` was not implemented.

There are a couple of feature requests in the Django tracker about this:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21265 (closed wontfix)
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21295 (patch accepted)

I don't know if the patch was integrated into any Django release. I'll leave that to you to research, or ask on a support forum.